# JNI call gets symbol lookup error for basic_stringstream declaration in my cpp shared library

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

**scenario:**
CCPJNI.java makes JNI call to CPPJNI.cpp which I build include in libCCBJNI.so
cpp code is executed correctly until it reaches stringstream declaration
then error:
java: symbol lookup error: .../libCCBJNI.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev

CCBJNI.cpp
.
.
out << "write 0 \r\n";
std::ostringstream ss;
cout << "write 1 \r\n";
.
.

Java compiles:
javac -cp ccb.jar:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc._s.so.1:libCCBJNI.so:json-simple-1.1.1.jar:azure-storage-4.2.0.jar CCBTEST.java

javac -cp ccb.jar:LIBCCBJNI.so:json-simple-1.1.1.jar:azure-storage-4.2.0.jar com/shiseido/ccb/CCBJNI.java

Java run:
java -cp .:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc._s.so.1:ccb.jar:libCCBJNI.so:jackson-core-2.12.0-rc1.jar:json-simple-1.1.1.jar:azure-storage-4.2.0.jar CCBTEST

**output:**
.
.
write 0
java: symbol lookup error: /mnt/c/Users/robsc/pahub-linux/pahub_scantech_platform_jniCopy7/Platform_JNI/CCBJNI/gdb2/CCBJNI/Remix/Source/libCCBJNI.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev

note: there is much more preceding code and preceding output that confirms the cpp code and standard libRARY are working fine other than the stringstream.

I am building libCCBJNI.so with visual Studio 2019 running on Windows and building for Linux

**question:**
How do I fix this?
Is stringstream in a separate cpp shared library?
If so what is the lib name, where can I it? How do I include it in my build and runtime?

Comment: What does `ldd libCCBJNI.so ` say? It should show a dependency on libstdc++ or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, it shows unresolved symbol for the basic_stringstream:                    U std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)     ..Its working now after reinstalling everything I think I had my environment wrong.  I'll answer this once I know what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Appears it was an environment issue.  After re-installing Ubuntu on Windows WSL and issue:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
it works with no unresolved symbols